# Everytime I open terminal on my Mac I get an /Users/shubh01/.zshrc:source:73: no such file or directory

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I recently changed my shell to zsh.
After changing my sheel to zsh I tried to install ohmyzsh, it worked good. After that I deleted ohmyzsh after running the uninstall zsh command.
Now, whenever I open my terminal on my mac I get the following error -
`/Users/user/.zshrc:source:73: no such file or directory: /Users/user/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh`

How do I remove this error message whenever I open my mac?
Below I have attached the file which I get after running the command `open /Users/user/.zshrc` on my mac.

```
# export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH

# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH="/Users/user/.oh-my-zsh"

# Set name of the theme to load --- if set to "random", it will
# load a random theme each time oh-my-zsh is loaded, in which case,
# to know which specific one was loaded, run: echo $RANDOM_THEME
# See https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Themes
ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"

# Uncomment the following line to automatically update without prompting.
# DISABLE_UPDATE_PROMPT="true"

# Uncomment the following line to change how often to auto-update (in days).
# export UPDATE_ZSH_DAYS=13

# Uncomment the following line if pasting URLs and other text is messed up.
# DISABLE_MAGIC_FUNCTIONS="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable colors in ls.
# DISABLE_LS_COLORS="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable auto-setting terminal title.
# DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to enable command auto-correction.
# ENABLE_CORRECTION="true"

# Uncomment the following line to display red dots whilst waiting for completion.
# COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to disable marking untracked files
# under VCS as dirty. This makes repository status check for large repositories
# much, much faster.
# DISABLE_UNTRACKED_FILES_DIRTY="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to change the command execution time
# stamp shown in the history command output.
# You can set one of the optional three formats:
# "mm/dd/yyyy"|"dd.mm.yyyy"|"yyyy-mm-dd"
# or set a custom format using the strftime function format specifications,
# see 'man strftime' for details.
# HIST_STAMPS="mm/dd/yyyy"

# Would you like to use another custom folder than $ZSH/custom?
# ZSH_CUSTOM=/path/to/new-custom-folder

# Which plugins would you like to load?
# Standard plugins can be found in $ZSH/plugins/
# Custom plugins may be added to $ZSH_CUSTOM/plugins/
# Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
# Add wisely, as too many plugins slow down shell startup.
plugins=(git)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

# User configuration

# export MANPATH="/usr/local/man:$MANPATH"

# You may need to manually set your language environment
# export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

# Preferred editor for local and remote sessions
# if [[ -n $SSH_CONNECTION ]]; then
#   export EDITOR='vim'
# else
#   export EDITOR='mvim'
# fi

# Compilation flags
# export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"

# Set personal aliases, overriding those provided by oh-my-zsh libs,
# plugins, and themes. Aliases can be placed here, though oh-my-zsh
# users are encouraged to define aliases within the ZSH_CUSTOM folder.
# For a full list of active aliases, run `alias`.
#
# Example aliases
# alias zshconfig="mate ~/.zshrc"
# alias ohmyzsh="mate ~/.oh-my-zsh"
```

Comment: The file `/Users/shubh01/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh` doesn't exist ; does the repertory exist? (Maybe a rights problem at install)

Comment: yes `/Users/shubh01/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh` doesn't exist. what do you suggest I do?

Comment: does the `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh` line in the `/Users/shubh01/.zshrc` have something to do with the issue as I unistalled ohmyzsh before?

Comment: Oh I missed the part you uninstalled ohmyzsh .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you uninstall ohmyzsh, the uninstall process can't guess and remove the now faulty line `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh`.

So you can remove it or comment it out with `#` in front.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove all the configurations from the `.zshrc` as they all contain the settings or configs related to `oh-my-zsh` only.

Answer (score 0):

Installing zsh doesn't install Oh My Zsh, which might explain why you don't have an `oh-my-zsh.sh` file at all (this was the case for me).

You can install Oh My Zsh by running

```
sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)"
```